# Why is Destructor Called when Copying?

Tags: c++

I have a serious problem where I use the default constructor to initialize objects and a constuctor with parameters to copy a DirectX Interface.

```
SpriteBatch spriteBatch; //Creating an Object to SpriteBatch Class

//This Function Gets Called when Device is Created with Parameter to Device
void LoadContent(GraphicDevice graphicDevice) 
{
  /*Here is the Problem, When it Assigns to the Object it creates a Temp Object and
  Destructor gets called where I free everything, I can't use the GraphicDevice after
  this.*/

  spriteBatch = SpriteBatch(graphicDevice); 
}


//SpriteBatch Class

class SpriteBatch
{
  GraphicDevice graphicDevice;

  public:
    SpriteBatch();
    SpriteBatch(GraphicDevice graphicDevice);
    ~SpriteBatch();
}

SpriteBatch::SpriteBatch()
{
}

SpriteBatch::SpriteBatch(GraphicDevice graphicDevice)
{
  this->graphicDevice = graphicDevice;
}

SpriteBatch::~SpriteBatch()
{
   graphicDevice-Release();
}
```

I want the destructor to get called when my program ends and not when I copy two objects.
I tried overloading the assignment operator and copy constructor which didn't help me though.
Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: It's how copying objects works. It's really as simple as that

Comment: How if I dont want the Destructor to get called when Copying ?

Answer (score 1):

Use a `shared_ptr` for the `graphicDevice` so that it will only get released when the reference count reaches zero. You should not be dealing with this in the destructor in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Pass by reference to reduce the number of copies, temporaries and their destruction:

```
void LoadContent(GraphicDevice& graphicDevice) 
{
    spriteBatch = SpriteBatch(graphicDevice); 
}
```

And then:

```
SpriteBatch::SpriteBatch(GraphicDevice& graphicDevice)
    :graphicDevice(graphicDevice)
{
}
```

If you want to avoid making a new `GraphicDevice` for each instance of `SpriteBatch`, make `GraphicDevice graphicDevice;` a reference:

```
GraphicDevice& graphicDevice;
```

This will need to be initialised in all of your `SpriteBatch` constructors.

Comment: I tried this, But Unfortunately Destructor still gets called which destroys the graphicDevice

Comment: @user2028359: ***When*** does the destructor get called? Also, it is the destruction which calls the destructor and not the other way around.